# Split Akka Stream Source into two

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have an Akka Streams `Source` which I want to split into two sources according to a predicate.

E.g. having a source (types are simplified intentionally):

```
val source: Source[Either[Throwable, String], NotUsed] = ???
```

And two methods:

```
def handleSuccess(source: Source[String, NotUsed]): Future[Unit] = ???
def handleFailure(source: Source[Throwable, NotUsed]): Future[Unit] = ???
```

I would like to be able to split the `source` according to `_.isRight` predicate and pass the right part to `handleSuccess` method and left part to `handleFailure` method.

I tried using `Broadcast` splitter but it requires `Sink`s at the end.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to split a source into two sources in such a way because these split sources can then be materialized separately and it is absolutely not clear how it should even work then.

Comment: Yes, I understand the implications of this. I'm interested in an alternative pattern to re-structure the code into. For example, I could make my methods return `Sink`s instead of accepting a `Source`.

Answer (score 10):

Although you can choose which side of the `Source` you want to retrieve items from it's not possible to create a `Source` that that yields two outputs which is what it seems like you would ultimately want.

Given the `GraphStage` below which essentially splits the left and right values into *two* outputs...

```
/**
  * Fans out left and right values of an either
  * @tparam L left value type
  * @tparam R right value type
  */
class EitherFanOut[L, R] extends GraphStage[FanOutShape2[Either[L, R], L, R]] {
  import akka.stream.{Attributes, Outlet}
  import akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic

  override val shape: FanOutShape2[Either[L, R], L, R] = new FanOutShape2[Either[L, R], L, R]("EitherFanOut")

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

    var out0demand = false
    var out1demand = false

    setHandler(shape.in, new InHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {

        if (out0demand && out1demand) {
          grab(shape.in) match {
            case Left(l) =>
              out0demand = false
              push(shape.out0, l)
            case Right(r) =>
              out1demand = false
              push(shape.out1, r)
          }
        }
      }
    })

    setHandler(shape.out0, new OutHandler {
      @scala.throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        if (!out0demand) {
          out0demand = true
        }

        if (out0demand && out1demand) {
          pull(shape.in)
        }
      }
    })

    setHandler(shape.out1, new OutHandler {
      @scala.throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
      override def onPull(): Unit = {
        if (!out1demand) {
          out1demand = true
        }

        if (out0demand && out1demand) {
          pull(shape.in)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

.. you can route them to only receive one side:

```
val sourceRight: Source[String, NotUsed] = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(source) { implicit b => s =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val eitherFanOut = b.add(new EitherFanOut[Throwable, String])

  s ~> eitherFanOut.in
  eitherFanOut.out0 ~> Sink.ignore

  SourceShape(eitherFanOut.out1)
})

Await.result(sourceRight.runWith(Sink.foreach(println)), Duration.Inf)
```

... or probably more desirable, route them to two seperate `Sink`s:

```
val leftSink = Sink.foreach[Throwable](s => println(s"FAILURE: $s"))
val rightSink = Sink.foreach[String](s => println(s"SUCCESS: $s"))

val flow = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(source, leftSink, rightSink)((_, _, _)) { implicit b => (s, l, r) =>

  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val eitherFanOut = b.add(new EitherFanOut[Throwable, String])

  s ~> eitherFanOut.in
  eitherFanOut.out0 ~> l.in
  eitherFanOut.out1 ~> r.in

  ClosedShape
})


val r = flow.run()
Await.result(Future.sequence(List(r._2, r._3)), Duration.Inf)
```

(Imports and initial setup)

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{GraphDSL, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.stage.{GraphStage, InHandler, OutHandler}
import akka.stream._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

val classLoader = getClass.getClassLoader
implicit val system = ActorSystem("QuickStart", ConfigFactory.load(classLoader), classLoader)
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val values: List[Either[Throwable, String]] = List(
  Right("B"),
  Left(new Throwable),
  Left(new RuntimeException),
  Right("B"),
  Right("C"),
  Right("G"),
  Right("I"),
  Right("F"),
  Right("T"),
  Right("A")
)

val source: Source[Either[Throwable, String], NotUsed] = Source.fromIterator(() => values.toIterator)
```

Answer (score 9):

---

**Edit**: [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64856373/147806) with `divertTo` is a better solution than mine, IMO. I'll leave my answer as-is for posterity.

---

*original answer:*

This is implemented in `akka-stream-contrib` as [`PartitionWith`](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/master/contrib/src/main/scala/akka/stream/contrib/PartitionWith.scala). Add this dependency to SBT to pull it in to your project:

````
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-contrib" % "0.9"```

`PartitionWith` is shaped like a `Broadcast(2)`, but with potentially different types for each of the two outlets. You provide it with a predicate to apply to each element, and depending on the outcome, they get routed to the applicable outlet. You can then attach a `Sink` or `Flow` to each of these outlets independently as appropriate. Building on [cessationoftime's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39744355/147806), with the `Broadcast` replaced with a `PartitionWith`:

    val eitherSource: Source[Either[Throwable, String], NotUsed] = Source.empty
    val leftSink = Sink.foreach[Throwable](s => println(s"FAILURE: $s"))
    val rightSink = Sink.foreach[String](s => println(s"SUCCESS: $s"))

    val flow = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(eitherSource, leftSink, rightSink)
                                      ((_, _, _)) { implicit b => (s, l, r) =>

      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val pw = b.add(
        PartitionWith.apply[Either[Throwable, String], Throwable, String](identity)
      )

      eitherSource ~> pw.in
      pw.out0 ~> leftSink
      pw.out1 ~> rightSink

      ClosedShape
    })

    val r = flow.run()
    Await.result(Future.sequence(List(r._2, r._3)), Duration.Inf)
````

Answer (score 5):

For this you can use a broadcast, then filter and map the streams within the GraphDSL:

```
val leftSink = Sink.foreach[Throwable](s => println(s"FAILURE: $s"))
val rightSink = Sink.foreach[String](s => println(s"SUCCESS: $s"))


val flow = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(eitherSource, leftSink, rightSink)((_, _, _)) { implicit b => (s, l, r) =>

       import GraphDSL.Implicits._

       val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Either[Throwable,String]](2))


       s ~> broadcast.in
       broadcast.out(0).filter(_.isLeft).map(_.left.get) ~> l.in
       broadcast.out(1).filter(_.isRight).map(_.right.get) ~> r.in


       ClosedShape
  })


val r = flow.run()
Await.result(Future.sequence(List(r._2, r._3)), Duration.Inf)
```

I expect you will be able to run the functions you want from within the map.

Comment: Bit safer variant of `.filter(_.isLeft).map(_.left.get)` is `.collect { case Left(l) => l }`
And so for the _right_ branch

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime this has been introduced to standard Akka-Streams: 
https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Partition.html.

You can split the input stream with a predicate and then use `collect` on each outputs to get only the types you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `divertTo` to attach alternative Sink to the flow to handle `Left`s: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/divertTo.html

```
source
  .divertTo(handleFailureSink, _.isLeft)
  .map(rightEither => handleSuccess(rightEither.right.get()))
```